# Saving the org-agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'd like to save the output of org-agenda to a text file, every time that the org-agenda is calculated. This way, I can use an external program (like ATNotes on windows or conky on linux), to pick up this text file and display it on my desktop.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like I'm raining on your parade after you went to the trouble to write this code snipped (and used a piece of around advice, too!), but actually this feature is already baked into org-mode, and documented in the manual.  The command you want is `org-write-agenda` (C-x C-w in an agenda buffer).  See the section of the org-mode info entitled "Exporting Agenda Views."

Comment: thanks. I wrote something similar some time back (a modification over the code written below), but this is better.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it while you have emacs open, you can just call `save-buffer` on the `*Agenda*` buffer via `M-x save-buffer` (since orgmode binds `C-x C-s` to `org-save-all-org-buffer.`  You could bind `save-buffer` to something else in the `org-mode-map` if you wanted.

If you want to do it via a cron, you should be able to use the snippet in [this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/6112) on the org-mode mailing list to pipe the output to a file.  I've used this in the past:

```
    emacs -batch -eval '(org-batch-agenda "a" org-agenda-ndays 7 org-agenda-include-diary nil org-agenda-files (quote ("~/org/todo.org")))' > agenda.txt
```

Comment: I don't want to be saving the buffer to a file each time I change something and re-calculate the agenda, and I'm looking for an entirely emacs based solution.

I was thinking along the lines of having to hook to function which calculates the agenda, or maybe using defadvice. Unfortunately, I don't know enough emacs lisp to try anything on my own.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally decided to open the emacs lisp manual and figure this out myself. I wrote this bit of code, which seems to be working just fine! :)

```
;; Save the org-agenda for display with conky
(defadvice org-todo-list (after saveorgagenda activate)
  "save this output to my todo file"
  (get-buffer-create "todo")
  (with-current-buffer "todo"
    (set-buffer-modified-p nil))
  (kill-buffer "todo")
  (write-file "~/todo"))
```

EDIT REASONS:

1) Without kill-buffer, the defadvice creates a new todo buffer on every execution of org-todo-list. This gets pretty irritating.

2) Without the get-buffer-create function, kill-buffers fails the first time since there is no buffer named todo at that time.

3) Without set-buffer-modified-p, the function will keep telling you "todo buffer is modified. Really kill it? (y or n)" which would defeat the whole purpose really.

Whew! I'm so happy I actually took the time and effort to figure this out! :D